# Table View Cell not loading

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to populate custom `UITableViewCell` inside `UITableView` but it's not loading the data in the cell. I have created an array of Recipes and populate the array with data from API call. after debugging the code, it seems that the array count is 0 hence not loading the data in the cell although I'm calling `getRecipes()` method to populate the array.. any idea on what's causing this or how to fix it??

Below is my code:

```swift
class MainPageViewController: UIViewController
{
    //declare variables
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeTableView: UITableView!
    var recipes: [Recipe] = []

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        recipeTableView.delegate = self
        recipeTableView.dataSource = self
        self.recipeTableView.reloadData()

        recipes = self.getRecipes()
        print("array: \(recipes.count)")
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
//ui table view functions
extension MainPageViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    //set the number of items in the table view to the array of objects
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        print("array count: \(recipes.count)")
        return recipes.count
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        recipeTableView.reloadData()
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    //fetch the data in the array and set it in the table view cells
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        print("code here")
        let recipe = self.recipes[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecipeCell")
            as! UIRecipeCell
        print("code here")
        cell.setRecipe(recipe: recipe)
        return cell;
    }

    func getRecipes() -> [Recipe]
    {
        var recipesTemp: [Recipe] = []
        // Hit Spoonacular endpoint using Moya as the middleman
        let provider = MoyaProvider<SpoonacularAPI>()
        provider.request(.getRecipes(limitLicense: true, number: 10, tags: "vegetarian, dessert"))
        {
            switch $0
            {
            case .success(let response):
                do {
                    // Only allow successful HTTP codes
                    _ = try response.filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()

                    // Parse data as JSON
                    let json = try JSON(data: response.data)
                    print("json log: \(json)")

                    // Parse each recipe's JSON
                    recipesTemp = json["recipes"].arrayValue.map({ Recipe(json: $0) })
                    print("array count: \(recipesTemp.count)")
                    print("array : \(recipesTemp)")
                }
                catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            self.recipeTableView.reloadData()

        }
        return recipesTemp
        recipeTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the parsing throwing any error?

Comment: @andromedainiative no, there's no error. I'm able to see the output of the array in the console.

Comment: Is `print("json log: \(json)")` printing? Reload the tableView in main thread once you get it.

Comment: Does it work if you mock the data and not do a request?

Comment: @Larme yes! I'm able to see the json. What do u mean by main thread?

Comment: Have you registered your cell before dequeing it?

Comment: @andromedainiative do u mean in the identifier in the storyboard? if yes, then I have already registered it.

Comment: You are returning RecipeData from your getRecipe() function and after that you have written tableView.reloadData() . Anything which is written after the return statement does not get executed.

Comment: @KeshuRai I did it everywhere to check. but it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API to get the recipes works asynchronously.

You cannot return anything from a method which contains an asynchronous task.

- In `viewDidLoad` call only the method.
- In `getRecipes` remove the return value, it's pointless.
- In the asynchronous closure assign the result to the data source array and reload the table view.
- And you might reload the table view on the main thread.

Alternatively use a completion handler.

---

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
   recipeTableView.delegate = self
   recipeTableView.dataSource = self
   getRecipes()
}

func getRecipes() 
{

    // Hit Spoonacular endpoint using Moya as the middleman
    let provider = MoyaProvider<SpoonacularAPI>()
    provider.request(.getRecipes(limitLicense: true, number: 10, tags: "vegetarian, dessert"))
    {
        switch $0
        {
        case .success(let response):
            do {
                // Only allow successful HTTP codes
                _ = try response.filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()

                // Parse data as JSON
                let json = try JSON(data: response.data)
                print("json log: \(json)")

                // Parse each recipe's JSON
                self.recipes = json["recipes"].arrayValue.map({ Recipe(json: $0) })
                print("array count: \(recipesTemp.count)")
                print("array : \(recipesTemp)")

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.recipeTableView.reloadData()
                }

            }

            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

And be aware you can **not** do something with `recipes` at the end of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I did as you said. I can see now the array is populated. however, my cell is not appearing.

Comment: yes multiple of times. I will update the console output in the question.

Comment: The code to populate the data source works. There is an issue with the cell. Is the identifier and the class of the cell set properly?

Comment: Try adding heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @vadian yes. I have set up the identifier in the storyboard.

Comment: Anyway the issue is not related to the question to populate the data source.

Comment: @vadian What kind of issue ?

Comment: The issue that nothing is displayed is related to the UI.

Comment: @vadian I tried to do the same thing with new table controller. still didn't work.

Comment: @vadian it seems that my table view cells are too small to show data.

Comment: As I said the issue is related to the UI which is another question.

Answer (score 0):

the issue here is that your request function return a result before the actual request hit the response

You should modify the logic with a completion handler instead

```
func getRecipes(complition: @escaping ((_ response: [Recipe]) -> ()))  {
// Your request logic 
// onSuccess return the array like this
// complition(resultArray)
}
```